# Hibernate save SQL exception

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

Hi guys I am trying to save an object to a MySQL data base via Hibernate. if I execute following code

```
 User user = new User();
     user.setData_1("my data 5");
     user.setFirstname("Freddy");
     user.setLastname("Bob");
     user.setId(5);
     session.save(user);
     session.getTransaction().commit();
```

I get a

> 'com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'xxx.my_table_1' doesn't exist'

exception. However, querying from the same table using the same config works just fine.

What could be the issue?

Comment: If your connection is telling you that a table doesnt exist, then clearly its able to get to your server and the server is responding that it doesnt have a table by that name.  what do you mean when you say you are querying from the same table?

Comment: I mean I can send a query, call .list() from it, and it returns a list of objects.

Comment: Also, if I execute same query as
Query q = session.createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO my_table_1 VALUES('DATA 5', 'Freddy', 'Bob', 5)");
q.executeUpdate();
it also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection string in the configuration something like `hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydatabase` You may be missing the schema name in the url(mydatabase).

Answer (score 0):

So, after some trial and error, I came to find out that the issue with the .get() (and apparently .save() too) was that I did not have a hibernate.default_schema set in config. Looks like it is used to create the 'dynamic' SQL for .save() and .get(), but if you use .createSQLQuery(), it just uses what ever String you pass as an argument for the SQL, and therefor works with out needing to have hibernate.default_schema set.